# How secure is JWT token visible after AWS Incognito callback

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, ping

I am using AWS Cognito which federates through ping, the response URL has http://localhost:3000/#access_token=AAAAAAAA&id_token=XXXXXXX&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=86400

How secure is this URL? (sniffs within the network)
what can we do to make it more secure?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AWS login page, you can also create your own login page/logout page etc in UI using amazon-cognito-identity-js where you need to provie userpool id and it returns back all the required token which you can use to authenticate the users.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=amazon+cognito+custom+login+page+episode+1